# c array with function and structures

Tags: c

I have to make c array through functions and structures. But I am not sure, how should I do that. Could you give me some tips?

Here is my version without functions and structures.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int i;
    float max, min, sum;
    float numbers[10];

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("put numbers: ");
        scanf("%f",&numbers[i]);
    }

   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%.2f \n ",numbers[i]);

    min = numbers[0];
    max = numbers[0];
    sum = 0;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(numbers[i]>max)
            max = numbers[i];
        if(numbers[i]<min)
            min = numbers[i];
        sum = sum + numbers[i];
    }

    printf("Minimum=%.2f; Maximum=%.2f; Prumer=%.2f",min,max,sum/10);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? I have not understood your question. Please clarify your problem.

Comment: i want to make array of structures and then make functions for calculate max min and avg.

Comment: @Jenik, did you already tried to create some structure or function?

Comment: just a little. i rather know something about theory.

Comment: The issue with have an array of structs is that you will probably have a `struct` with one element, which is always odd. Unless that is fine with you, then I suggest not using an array of structs. Why not simply a `struct` with a `float` array, along with the max, min and avg values?

Comment: Thanks to all. It helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct t_numbers {
  float max;
  float min;  
};

t_numbers num [10];

...
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
  num[i].max = 0;
  num[i].min = 0;
}
```

You must get the idea. ;-)
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    float max;
    float min;
    float avg;
} Result_t;

void ask_numbers(float *numbers, int nelem)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<nelem;i++)
    {
        printf("put numbers: ");
        scanf("%f",&numbers[i]);
    }
}

Result_t calculate(const float *numbers, int nelem)
{
    int i;
    float sum = 0.0f;
    Result_t res = {0};

    res.min = numbers[0];
    res.max = numbers[0];

    for(i=0; i<nelem; i++) {
        if(numbers[i] > res.max)
            res.max = numbers[i];

        if(numbers[i] < res.min)
            res.min = numbers[i];

        sum += numbers[i];
    }

    res.avg = sum / nelem;

    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int i;
    float numbers[10];
    Result_t res;

    ask_numbers(numbers, 10);

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%.2f \n ",numbers[i]);


    res = calculate(numbers, 10);

    printf("Minimum=%.2f; Maximum=%.2f; Prumer=%.2f", res.min, res.max, res.avg);

    return(0);
}
```

On the second function, the struct could have been passed by pointers instead to be returned by copy. But since the struct is small, the overhead is small.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want an **array of structs**, you can create a singular struct holding one `float` member:

```
typedef struct {
    float number;
} number_t;
```

**Note:** Having a `struct` with one member is awkward, but it will suffice for your needs. It would be better to just declare a `float` array and have that in one struct, but that would not be an array of structs.

You can then create an array of structs:

```
number_t numbers[10];
```

Which has 10 members of type `number_t`. You can then have this array sit inside a larger struct which holds the max, min and average values:

```
typedef struct {
    number_t numbers[MAXNUM];
    size_t size;
    float max;
    float min;
    float avg;
} numbers_t;
```

You can then pass something like `numbers_t N` to `main()`, which declares a struct member of type `numbers_t`. This member holds the whole struct.

In order to modify the contents of `N`, you can simply pass a pointer to it, and change the contents by accessing the address of this pointer.

Additionally, it is always good to check result of `scanf()`, just to be safe.

### Here is some example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXNUM 10

typedef struct {
    float number;
} number_t;

typedef struct {
    number_t numbers[MAXNUM];
    size_t size;
    float max;
    float min;
    float avg;
} numbers_t;

/* functions which pass pointer to N */
void initialize_struct(numbers_t *N);
void print_details(numbers_t *N);
void print_array(numbers_t *N);
void get_input(numbers_t *N);
void get_data(numbers_t *N);

int main(void) {
    numbers_t N;

    initialize_struct(&N);

    get_input(&N);

    get_data(&N);

    print_details(&N);

    return 0;
}

void print_details(numbers_t *N) {
    print_array(N);
    printf("\nMaximum: %.2f\n", N->max);
    printf("\nMinimum: %.2f\n", N->min);
    printf("\nAverage: %.2f\n", N->avg);
}

void print_array(numbers_t *N) {
    printf("\nYour numbers:\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N->size; i++) {
        printf("%.2f\n", N->numbers[i].number);
    }
}

void get_input(numbers_t *N) {
    printf("Enter %zu numbers:\n", N->size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N->size; i++) {
        if (scanf("%f", &N->numbers[i].number) != 1) {
            printf("Invalid number entered\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

void get_data(numbers_t *N) {
    float sum = 0.0f;
    N->max = N->min = N->numbers[0].number;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < N->size; i++) {
        if (N->numbers[i].number > N->max) {
            N->max = N->numbers[i].number;
        } else if (N->numbers[i].number < N->min) {
            N->min = N->numbers[i].number;
        }
        sum += N->numbers[i].number;
    }
    N->avg = sum / N->size;
}

void initialize_struct(numbers_t *N) {
    N->size = MAXNUM;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N->size; i++) {
        N->numbers[i].number = 0.0f;
    }

    N->max = 0.0f;
    N->min = 0.0f;
    N->avg = 0.0f;
}
```

**Example input:**

```
Enter 10 numbers:
5.43
4.32
9.43
10.43
7.43
2.34
1.54
8.43
6.43
4.32
```

**Output:**

```
Your numbers:
5.43
4.32
9.43
10.43
7.43
2.34
1.54
8.43
6.43
4.32

Maximum: 10.43

Minimum: 1.54

Average: 5.47
```